# how to open a custom dailog box onclick of quickfix marker in eclipse RCP?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

[In line number 6 , when clicked on marker how to open a custom
MarkerResolutionSelectionDialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sftf6.png) I am developing a RCP plugin, can anyone suggest me how to open a custom dialog box onclick of quickfix marker and display the suggested quickfix in the dialog box?

Comment: This is very broad, which part of the quick fix code are you having problems with? The Eclipse help has quite a lot on quick fixes.

Comment: quickfix is working fine.. i want to attach a dailogbox with  custom marker

Comment: Looks like you would do this in your `IMarkerResolution` / `IMarkerResolution2` class

Comment: you mean calling the dailogbox in public IMarkerResolution[] getResolutions(IMarker marker)?

Comment: No, I mean in the `run` method in an implementation of `IMarkerResolution` that you provide. That is what JDT does to open preference and property pages,

Comment: okay.. i tried placing MyDialog d = new MyDialog(Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell());
 int status = d.open(); this code inside public void run(IMarker marker) method .. but its not opening the dialog .. could you pls tell me where am doing wrong . or how shall i proceed onclick of marker a custom dialog opens and display the quickfix

Comment: No, I can't tell you, I am just looking at what Eclipse JDT does. You need to do some debugging, is the run method being called for example?

Comment: yes run method is called but if there are 3 errors the dialog box opens 3 times .. but what i want is onclick of marker the dialog should open and display the quickfix in the dialog